# Angular 6 -"generic type elementref requires 2 type arguments", couldn`t use it

Tags: angular

I try to use ElementRef, using this import:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

I have tried to inject in the construtor as directed in all examples.

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private elm: ElementRef) { }
```

It gives me an error:

> "generic type 'elementref t any ' requires 2 type argument(s)"

Also have tried to use it this way:

```
@ViewChild("user") elmUser: ElementRef;
```

But that results in the same error.

How do I correctly do that?

Comment: pls show some more code...

Comment: This is all code about ElementRef, Kindly let me know what more I have to share

Comment: Error is somewhere else. Better you share entire ts code.

Comment: They changed it, so you have to write: `ElementRef<HtmlElement>`.

Comment: can you share a link for example ElementRef<HtmlElement>

Comment: My entire code is in https://codeshare.io/5PQrv7

Comment: Did you share the code for ApiService & ToastrService ?

Comment: No, but that code is working fine, do you want me to share

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: And when people tell you to share code, you should provide a [mcve]. It is not about ALL code, just enough code to understand where the problem is coming from. That is also helpful when debugging things - isolate first, to figure: "what is the minimal code leading to the error"

Comment: Thanks for editing, let me post questions as this, can u help with the issue

Answer (score 0):

[`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) expects a `Type: T` for it's `nativeElement` property:

> ```
> class ElementRef<T> {
>   constructor(nativeElement: T)
>   nativeElement: T
> }
> ```

Try using it like this:

```
constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
  private elm: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
) { }
```

and

```
@ViewChild("user") elmUser: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

It used to work before. But probably they changed it recently.

Comment: Unbelievable. Try breaking your server once and try rebuilding and serving your app.

Comment: my IDE is visual studio, the error is still there in visual studio

Comment: This is my code for reference, my angular version is 6

Comment: @mano10 But does `ng serve` complains? Otherwise it looks like Visual Studio might be wrong.

Comment: ng serve didn`t complain, but when I try having a breakpoint and check attributes of elementref it is null, so, I think something is really wrong

Comment: My angular version 6.2.5